# Stack Size, FRDM-KL46Z IAR?

Tags: c, linker, stack, iar, cortex-m

There seems to be some sort of paradox, that I am not able to configure the correct Stack Size for FRDM-KL46Z for IAR compiler.

I am using the FRDM-Demo example provided from freescale for IAR compiler.

I go to project linker settings, and modified `CSTACK` to 33*1024 (Enormous)

[image]

Then I RE Build the program, surprisingly it build Successful - OK.

I checked the `256_pflash.icf` linker file, shows cstack = 33*1024.

[image]

Then, I go to map file of the project.

[image]

Questions:

1. Why is map file not showing the Stack Size value, in the Highlighted Linker created area?
2. How was IAR abled to Build, by configure 33*1024 Bytes of Stack size, while total RAM of FRDM-KL46Z is 32 KB only?

Please, explain anyone what is happening, actually I want to increase the stack size, but now I am not sure if I am using the right linker files or not.

And, I am doing this because I am facing a HardFault error. This is why I was trying to increase stack size.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you find `CSTACK` from map file? Does it work without multiplication (`33792`, not `33*1024`)?

Comment: @user694733 No! Ive tried without multiplication. Yes! I see CSTACK in linker file. do you want the see the linker file?

Comment: show only lines with CSTACK in it. Anyway, you should try smaller stack size first, something that will surely work.

Comment: @user694733 ok! In map file

`"P2": place in [from 0x1fffe410 to 0x20006000] {

      rw, block CodeRelocateRAM, block CSTACK, block HEAP};`

Comment: @user694733 Actually, I require high Stack in my program, around 6-7K. But, I am not able to make sure, if my assigned stack size is actually working.

Comment: @user694733 In the linker file

`define symbol __ICFEDIT_size_cstack__ = (33*1024);
`

Comment: Try maybe 10 or 16kB first. It makes no sense to go for 33kB if you only have 32kB.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55836/discussion-between-ishmeet-and-user694733).